# Digital "Post It" notes for organizing content of sites/pages

Tags: sitemap, content, architecture

We're restructuring our old intranet into a new one and are going through each site to find content and use our new standard structure/look-and-feel. Do you recommend a tool where you can do "digital Post-It" notes? It would provide a way to type some items on a "card" and be able to move it around and organize it quickly.

Also, if you know of tools in general for this kind of task, please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [Card sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_sorting) the sort of thing you mean? There are lots of online tools for this, e.g [Optimal sort](http://www.optimalworkshop.com/optimalsort.htm), plenty more if you google it.

Comment: Thanks, Brightly. I didn't know the term to search on. Learned something new: "card sorting".

Comment: I would add that this is something fun that can be done offline as well, using literal post-it notes.  If you get all the required parties into a room and get them to order content in front of each other it could speed the development of the site up and remove some of the internal politics of departments fighting for space.

Comment: Glad I could help!